# Simple perl array function doesn't work

Tags: perl

This simple Perl script is translating stories from a database into XML, but this one section is giving me problems. The function `makeUrl` is called for each story, but needs to ensure that duplicate URLs aren't created.

```
my @headlines = ();
my $hlCount = 1;
.
.
.

sub makeUrl {
  my $headline;
  open( URLSOUT, '>>/var/mtkoan/harris/urls' );

  $url = $_[0];
  print URLSOUT "Before: $url\n";
  $url =~ s/\x{90}//g;
  $url =~ s/\s+$//g;
  $url =~ s/^\s+//g;
  $url =~ s/\s/_/g;
  $url =~ s/\W//g;

  push @headlines, $url;
  foreach $headline (@headlines) {
    if( $headline eq $url ) {
      $url .= "_$hlCount";
      $hlCount++;
    }
  }

  print URLSOUT "After: $url\n\n";
  print URLSOUT "Headline Array Dump:\n";
  print URLSOUT "@headlines\n";
  close URLSOUT;
}
```

When the array is printed, only the last value is shown. Push isn't appending to the end of the array, I can't figure it out!

Comment: here is the full script: http://pastebin.com/6SXe5ZSd

Comment: Oof, Switch.  That thing can cause nasty problems.  Consider rewriting using given/when (if you're on 5.10 or newer) or if/else otherwise.  Switch just looks pretty; it won't actually make the program really any faster.

Comment: I don't see why it's not working, but it would make more sense to use a hash instead of an array.  Then you wouldn't need to loop through the array to see if there's a dupe; it would just be a simple hash lookup.

Comment: I didn't notice the Switch.  For this particular use, both of the functions using `switch` can be replaced by constant hashes.  They'll be faster, and you won't need `use Switch`.

Comment: You should really consider using lexical file handles and 3 argument open.  There's a ton of stuff on SO about how to use them and why they are better.

Comment: excellent, grateful for the help with my perl fu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check for uniqueness (and remove duplicates from a list) in two main ways:

With a hash:

```
    my %urls;
    # construct your URL in the function...
    $urls{$url}++;

    # get all the (unique) URLs:
    my @urls = keys %urls;
```

With a library call that returns the unique values in a list (see [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List::MoreUtils)):

```
    use List::MoreUtils 'uniq`;
    @urls = uniq @urls;
```